# ÆØÅ doesn't display correctly in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have set up a table in phpMyAdmin. I haven't changed the charsets or anything. I inserted a text in a new row, and when I try to SELECT that row and output it with PHP, the letters ÆØÅ are displayed as ���, however if I try to edit the field in phpMyAdmin, the letters are displayed correctly. What do I do wrong that phpMyAdmin does correctly?

Comment: What is the character set of your table / column and what is the character set you're using in PHP? This sounds like either the database or the client is using a character set that doesn't includes these characters.

Comment: I'm having some similar trouble. When I upload text with those characters from my app, they don't seem to be getting added to my SQL table online.

Comment: MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Table collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: Coloumn collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: HTML: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

Comment: Use `iconv`/`mb_convert_encoding` to convert content before output or change DB collation. Second is the better option, but will have to dump the DB, convert, drop the tables and import after that (at least this will be the easiest way)

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, I can change the collation. Isn't this going to work if the collection of my choice is wrong? (It didn't work.)

Comment: Server: localhost (localhost via TCP/IP)
    Server version: 5.5.20-log
    Protocol version: 10
    User: root@localhost
    MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your PHP file is already UTF-8 encoded, you should tell your database, that you need UTF-8. Instead of fiddling with the configurations of MySQL, just tell your connection object, which character-set you expect, the database does the rest for you.

This is an example for a mysqli connection object:

```
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPw, $dbName);
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Afterwards your queries will return UTF-8 encoded results.

Comment: This did work! I see that it is utf8, but why is there no utf8 as an alternative to collation in phpMyAdmin? How would I go about doing this correctly? I suppose it is better to save the data correctly in the first place? And is there any impact on the speed?

Comment: @Student of Hogwarts - The collation does not determine how the string is stored, it only determines how a comparison of two strings is done (at least that's how i understand it).

Comment: Yes, I'm reading about it now. Hmm, why can't they have a master-charset like we have in HTML: UTF-8...

Comment: @Student of Hogwarts - Im not completely sure about this myself. When i create a new database in phpMyAdmin and choose the collation `utf8_unicode_ci` for the db, then an export of the db will contain `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`, so i assume it is indeed stored with charset UTF-8. Setting the charset for the client (PHP connection object) is a different story though, and should be done to be independend of whatever default settings the server has.

Comment: Mm, so it is still best to get MySQL right, since this is always going to have to work with æøå.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NAMES 'charset_name'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: replace 'charset_name' with charset you are working with, for example:
SET NAMES utf8;

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NAMES 'utf8''

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to determine if it is the browser charset that is wrong, or mysql.
Try swapping the charset in your browser to utf8 or if it is already to iso-8859.

If that doesn't fix it try changing the charset in your query by doing

```
SET CHARACTER SET charsetname;
```